# I'm trying to use 'Firebase/MLVision' pod but getting below error after installing the pod

Tags: swift5

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fEqual", referenced from:
      -[FIRVisionPoint isEqual:] in FirebaseMLVision(FIRVisionPoint_ed9ba191dd39cfa4dcbfad6e343d54bb.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBMLx_GMVFaceInitializationOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseMLVision(FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions_7977a11f37f876d536fa69c1aa1d0436.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Consider to know users what you've tried/did so far.

Comment: I've tried changing the Enabled Bitcode option to "NO" and the deleted the Xcode Derived Data but no use.